# Gradle Project Dependencies not being found

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, gradle

Trying to build Java gwt Gradle multiproject in eclipse
But cannot get a reference of project 2 into project 3
Any suggestion greatly appreciated.

Structure 3 projects

Project 1 TmsRoot (master project)

Project 2 CommonGWT (GWT Code)

Project 3 Common  (Non Gwt) Depends on CommonGWT

settings.gradle file in TmsRoot project

```
rootProject.name = "TmsRoot"

include ":ConmonGWT", ":Common"
```

TmsRoot build.gradle

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'

repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
}

version = '1.0'

jar {
    manifest.attributes provider: ' Technologies'
}
}
```

CommonGWT build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'gwt'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'jetty'
dependencies {
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

 sourceCompatibility = 1.7

 targetCompatibility = 1.7

 version = '1.0'

 buildscript {
 repositories {
     jcenter() //repository where to fetch gwt gradle plugin
 }
 dependencies {
    classpath 'de.richsource.gradle.plugins:gwt-gradle-plugin:0.6'
 }
 }
 repositories {
    mavenCentral()
 }

 compileJava{
    //enable incremental compilation
    options.incremental = true
 }
 gwt {
    gwtVersion='2.7.0'
    modules 'com.stratebo.gwt.common'

    sourceSets {
         main {
            java {
                srcDir 'src'
            }
        }
    }
    logLevel = 'ERROR'

    minHeapSize = "512M";
    maxHeapSize = "1024M";

    superDev {
    noPrecompile=true
    }
    eclipse{
        addGwtContainer=false // Default set to true
    }
    jettyRunWar.httpPort = 8089
 }
 task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
     gradleVersion = '2.8'
 }


 task jettyDraftWar(type: JettyRunWar) {
    dependsOn draftWar
    dependsOn.remove('war')
    webApp=draftWar.archivePath
 }
```

And finally the Common build.graddle

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

dependencies {

compile project(':CommonGWT')
}
```

If I hit gradle refresh dependencies
I get the following result
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Files\Data\Devel6\Common\build.gradle' line: 8
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Common'.
  Project with path ':CommonGWT' could not be found in root project 'Common'.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems to me, all your 3 project directories are on the same level. I mean, root project directory doespn't contain within directories of subprojects, as:

```
.
├── TMsRoot
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── settings.gradle
├── CommonGWT
│   └── build.gradle
└── Common
    └── build.gradle
```

In that case, then settings.gradle file is not on the root directory of the subprojects, it must contain not `include`, but `includeFlat`, to specify subprojects.

Comment: hanks it works,  After hours of googling never saw any reference to includeFlat. i will sleep better tonght

Comment: @LouisBiron you are welcome. Was trying to find this in the official manual, to provide a reference, but with no luck. Furthermore, such a projects structure could lead to some problems, for example, it could be not possible to build common project separately, because it'll not find a commonGwt project, since it hes no setting.gradle file in root directories

Comment: It looks like it is compiling now but I will move the projects so that it does not bite me in the future